# Call JavaScript function from JsRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I have a JsRender template. When template is rendering I want to call a JavaScript function to manipulate some data.

Here is my JsRender template.

```
<tr class="template-download">
   <td class="size">
        <span>{{:size}}</span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to pass `:size` value to JavaScript function and get the return value. So I can show return value instead of `:size` value.

My JavaScript function is

```
function getSize(size) {
    var megabytes = size / (1024 * 1024);
    return megabytes.toFixed(2) + "MB";
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this by using a helper function.  When you call render, you can define and pass a helper function 'into' your template:

```
$("#tmpl").render(data, {
    getSize: function(size) {
        var megabytes = size / (1024 * 1024);
        return megabytes.toFixed(2) + "MB";
    }
});
```

Then, in your template, you call the helper function like this:

```
<tr class="template-download">
   <td class="size">
        <span>{{:size}} {{:~getSize(size)}} </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I've made a couple of assumptions about how your template is being used, but this should get you going.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975379.aspx) has a section related to helper functions, and @BorisMoore has a number of good examples on his [jsViews site](http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers).

Comment: Yes, thanks - that JsViews site link (http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers) is the best current documentation link for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must use helper functions.  See the two references below.  The 2nd is a fully flushed out example.

http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/09_helper-functions.html

Comment: BTW, the best current documentation link in this is http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers