# Pass C# variable to helper function in jsrender template

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, jsrender

I need to pass one of my model value to the function in jsrender template. I tried using @ for accessing the C# variable, but its not working. Below is my code

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="TemplateDate">>
 {{:~formatTemplateDate(Model.EstimatedCompletionDate)}} 
</script>
```

This is my helper function.

```
$.views.helpers({
    formatTemplateDate: function (dateEstimated) {
        "use strict";
        if (dateEstimated !== null) {
            if (!isSafari) {
                var options = {
                    year: "numeric",
                    month: "short",
                    day: "numeric",
                    hour: "2-digit",
                    minute: "2-digit"
                };
                return dateEstimated.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
            } else {
                return dateEstimated;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the error i get in the page

`Error: n.toLocaleDateString is not a function.`

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh.

Comment: Refer the below question , which may helps u
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948193/call-javascript-function-from-jsrender

Comment: My problem is passing a model value to the helper function.

Comment: Where does that "jsrender" script live? The `@` will only work inside of razor views, not in plain html or js files.

Comment: And please define "not working". Do you see errors (if so, please specify - also check the javascript console)? What do you see in the rendered html ("view source" in the browser)?

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, am using jsrender inside my razor view. i have updated the question with the error detail.

Comment: So either you are trying to execute this on a browser that doesn't support that method, or some other problem: what are the values of `isSafari` and `dateEstimated` inside that formatter function? What is the value that gets inserted into the *call* to your formatter function?

Comment: the value of isSafari is false and dateEstimated is "undefined".

Comment: I checked the value for Model.EstimatedCompletionDate, its not null. its having the datetime value. Model.EstimatedCompletionDate is a DateTime variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fix. We cannot pass the @Model.EstimatedCompletion datetime variable value to the helper function. Need to convert it to string and in the helper function need to convert it back to Datetime(). below is the modified code.

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="TemplateDate">>
 {{:~formatTemplateDate('@Model.EstimatedCompletionDate')}} 
</script>
```

In my helper function, am converting it back to date type, **var formatedDate = new Date(date);**

```
$.views.helpers({
    format: function (date) {
        "use strict";
        var formatedDate = new Date(date);
        if (!isSafari) {
            var options = {
                year: "numeric",
                month: "short",
                day: "numeric"
            };
            return formatedDate.toLocaleDateString("en-us", options);
        } else {
            return formatedDate;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks,

Dinesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value to the function using `@Html.Raw()`:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="TemplateDate">>
     {{:~formatTemplateDate('@Html.Raw(Model.EstimatedCompletionDate))')}} 
</script>
```

Comment: What error is it giving you? What is the value shown in the page source?

Comment: Error: n.toLocaleDateString is not a function. this is the error am getting in my page.